# How to bind an object to the label in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have  labels with footballer's names inside. I want to get footballer's age after clicking on these labels. I do it by this way:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Footballer[] team = { /*team initialization*/};
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void OnLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < team.Length; i++)
        {
            if (team[i].Name == this.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(team[i].Age.ToString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But there is problem. There might be more than one player with the same name. So I want to bind each label with footballer. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you set the Labels text? In that point you could add your Footballer object to the Tag property and retrieve it when you want to display info about that single instance

Comment: How are the labels being created and populated? In the designer? Or in code? Also, please share the class definition of `Footballer`.

Answer (score 1):

For sake of simplicity suppose that you initialize your labels in this mode....

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    int index = 0;
    foreach(Label lbl in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    {
        lbl.Text = team[index].Name;

        // Make the Tag property reference the Footballer instance  
        // used to set the label text with the footballer name
        lbl.Tag = team[index];
        index++;
    }
```

At this point, when you receive the click event, you just need to retrieve the reference from the Tag property and use it directly

```
    private void OnLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // No loop needed here
        Label current = sender as Label;
        Footballer player = current.Tag as Footballer;
        if(player != null)
            MessageBox.Show(player.Age.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should separate out your business logic from your presentation logic.  The name is what you presented, but to keep each player/team unique then assign a unique ID.

This is then assigned to the label but hidden from view, so that when the label is clicked the ID is retrieved and you can then do a lookup based on this.

So with Player class like the following:

```
public class Player
{
   public int ID { get;set; }
   public string Name { get;set; }
   //etc.
}
```

Then when assigning a Player to label use Label.Tag which is a general purpose field which you can use for anything your want. (Available on all Controls).

```
label1.Text = MyPlayer.Name;
label1.Tag = MyPlayer.ID;
```

If I was you, I would also change your Teams to be a List not an array

```
List<Footballer> team = new List<Footballer>() { /*team initialization*/};
```

Then you can look up as follows

```
private void OnLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Label clickedLabel = (sender as Label);
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(clickedLabel.Tag);
      Footballer found = team.Find(x => x.Id == id);
      MessageBox.Show(found.Age.ToString());
}
```